# form_remote_for using put to different action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionview

i need to make "put" request, to "/users/upload_image" action.

Following code:

```
<% form_remote_for @user, :url => "/users/upload_image?id=#{@user.id}", :method => :put, :html => { :multipart => true } do |upload_form| %>
    <%= upload_form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

Produces following HTML:

```
<form action="/users/1234567" method="post" onsubmit="$.ajax({data:$.param($(this).serializeArray()) + '&amp;authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('HMkaYvfHyyYR1jGpVPkyLPfkPacqvTvtHjgDowzwzuY='), dataType:'script', type:'post', url:'/users/1234567'}); return false;">
```

When i set :method => :put in :html param, it will be set only in HTML, instead of JavaScript code.

1. I need to have "put" inside the form tag and JavaScript
2. I need to have action, like "/users/upload_image"

How to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll look below `<form>` tag you'll see:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

That because HTTP doesn't support `PUT` and `DELETE` methods. It supports only `GET` and `POST` so Rails immitates PUT method this way

**UPD**

About ajax file uppload: [Ruby on Rails AJAX file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379204/ruby-on-rails-ajax-file-upload)

to add `/users/:id/upload_image` path you should edit your routes and controller:

```
# routes to get /users/:id/upload_image
map.resources :user, :member => {:upload_image => :put}

# users_controller
def upload_image
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Now you can use `upload_image_user_path(@user)` that will generate `/users/@user.id/upload_image` url for you

**UPD 2**

If you want to get `/users/upload_image?user_id=XXX`

```
# config/routes.rb
map.resources :user, :collection => {:upload_image => :put}

# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def upload_image
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes. I see. Thanks. How can i customize :url ?

Comment: Thanks. I already have working uploading code. But this request was handled in /users/update method. Since, they are different scenarios, i need to have a separate action, called /users/upload_image". The only thing, i need now, is to change action in form_remote_for. Setting different :url does't gives any effect.

Comment: new update. But, actually, I didn't understand whole picture.

Comment: I just need to implement avatar uploading in a separate controller's action. Thanks ! I works !